# Spring Boot - Inject service into unmanaged object with @Configurable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

I'm trying to adopt rich domain model in my Spring Boot application which requires me to inject some components into `@Entity` objects which are not managed by Spring.

My project is built by Gradle and also uses Lombok.

I've tried using `@Configurable` annotation, but the component that should be autowired into the entity is always null no matter what I try.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving' version '8.4'
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.20'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    ...
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

Application.java:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Entity.java:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configurable
class Entity {

    @Autowired
    private transient SomeDependency someDependency;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

SomeDependency.java:

```java
@Component
public class SomeDependency {
    ...
}
```

I use Freefair aspectj.post-compile-weaving plugin because the basic version doesn't work alongside Lombok. I would like to avoid using load time weaving if possible because of the increased complexity to run the application.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any comprehensive tutorial which you could point me to? Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need the AspectJ compiler? I see no aspects here. And how is the aspect question related to injecting a Spring component into one not managed by Spring? If you cannot explain it, please share a complete, minimal project.

Comment: All sources regarding this topic indicate that some kind of AspectJ weaving, be it compile time or load time, is necessary to be able to properly use @Configurable annotation and inject a bean into an unmanaged object.

I've created a simple demo project: https://github.com/fugasjunior/spring-configurable-demo, closely following a related tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source.

There's a test that should pass. Currently it fails on NPE: `Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.IdService.generateId()" because "this.idService" is null`.

Comment: Did you include `spring-aspects` as a dependency? As that includes the needed aspects to do the injection, without these aspects nothing is going to happen.

Comment: I did, the example project includes `implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '6.0.13'` dependency. I also tried using `spring-boot-starter-aop`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: I also noticed that in the log, there's a following message: "SpringPersistenceUnitInfo: No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer". Makes me think whether injecting into JPA Entities is even possible without load time weaving?

Comment: That last message is for something else, also don't specify a version for dependencies when using Spring Boot else you endup with incompatible versions.

Comment: Finally as you are using an external dependency for aspects and not aspects from your local source, shouldn't the `spring-aspect` be defined as an `aspect` scope instead of `implementation` or probably even both? Else aspectj compilation will not see the aspects.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `aspect group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '6.0.13'` finally worked. I'll keep playing around with this to see what parts are actually necessary.

Comment: _"All sources regarding this topic indicate that some kind of AspectJ weaving (...) is necessary"_ Yes, you are right. My remark, that in your code or configuration there was no idicator of any aspects, was meant to lead you to the insight that something in that picture was not right - namely, that `spring-aspects` was missing. Just like M. Deinum said: no aspects → no aspect behaviour.